# Iis it possible to lock a file in Linux so it can't be read if another process has it open for writing?

Tags: linux, filesystems

We all know that Linux/Unix will automatically block attempts to write to a file that currently open for writing by another process. But is it possible to block/lock **read access** to a file if another process has it open for writing? I've got two different scripts, both start at random times and run various times during the day: one script overwrites a particular file; the other one reads from that file. I want the second one to block(wait) or fail if the first one has the file open.

Comment: "We all know that Linux/Unix will automatically block attempts" - no it doesn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [flock(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/flock) utility may do what you want

- Take out a write lock on the file when you want to overwrite it

  flock -x /path/to/lockfile somecommand file
- Have the other command check for the lock.

  flock -n /path/to/lockfile anothercommand file

If the file is locked then you get an exit code of 1 otherwise it's yours and you can do what you want with it

Doc:

> -x, -e, --exclusive Obtain an exclusive lock, sometimes called a write lock. This is the default.

> -n, --nb, --nonblock Fail (with an exit code of 1) rather than wait if the lock cannot be immediately acquired.

Comment: This worked. I launch my write process with `flock -x` and i launch my read process with `flock -s`. The read process blocks until the write process has completed. If there is no write process running, the read simply reads right away. Thanks!

Comment: This solution however does not prevent [TOCTOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use) race conditions

Comment: Just to clarify, `flock` provides an `advisory` lock in contrast to `mandatory`. Therefore, a process which does not rely on `flock`, knows the `*.lock` file destination or similar, or `/proc/locks` will highly likely and cheerfully modify the file. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1040869/5113030 (*How do I use the linux flock command to prevent another root process from deleting a file?*...)
More to that. Mandatory locks in Unix are generally special filesystems which are virtual (VFS) and, traditionally, no hardware supports file locking at all.

Comment: To clarify, the OP is controlling the scripts using the (f)lock.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have complete un-synchronize running.. You could do something simple which is to have the "writing" process create the new file with a temp name say .tmp so if the file it will create is output1.txt it would work in output1.txt.tmp.

Once the writer is done the last thing it does is a mv command.

From here you can do two things. One have the reader not care because since the tmp file is a different inode, the mv will not hurt it (Linux will keep it alive as long as it has a consumer) and the next read will have the new file..

(as long as it would not hurt you to run with the old file one last time).

The other option is that the reader looks for the tmp file and block while that file exists (this becoming a sort of lock file).

Comment: Yes, I thought about the temp file thing. I've done that before. And if there's no other solutions this is what I'll do, but I'm curious if there's more of a "builtin" linux solution. It looks like the `flock` suggestion above might do it.

Comment: Nice and it cleans the lock when the process closes.. nice.

Comment: So you can't mv a file to another file if that other file has a consumer? Or will mv wait?

Comment: @JohnyTex, no the mv will occur right away aka the inode to the content of the file for that directory entry will change immediately. However, any process that had the file open before will still reference the old content. That will be truly deleted/remove once the last process closes the file.
This is better post to explain: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028874/what-happens-to-an-open-file-handle-on-linux-if-the-pointed-file-gets-moved-or-d#:~:text=The%20file%20will%20not%20really%20be%20deleted%20until,still%20be%20valid%20and%20access%20the%20new%20content.

Answer (score 2):

Not being eligible (yet :-)) to comment on a question let me
warn readers on the question's false statement, through "answering":

> We all know that linux/Unix will automtically block attemtps to write
> to a file that currently open for writing by another process.

My proof bases on `man 2 open,write` that do not discourage from attempting which of course has been done by myself.
For further learning on the question I recommend [a decent discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942915/understanding-concurrent-file-writes-from-multiple-processes).

If my warning is still unsuitable (does not answer the asker's question) instead of deleting it I suggest to copy it by someone creditable under the question comments section. After verification of course. Thank you.

Comment: This actually is an answer - it's called a [frame challenge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263661/does-stack-exchange-allow-for-answers-which-question-the-validity-or-stance-of-t).